# Memsql and MySql installation in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu-14.04, singlestore

I would like to know that is it possible to install memsql and Mysql both on the same server ? If so is it a good practice ?

```
Server : Ubuntu 14.04
RAM    : 8 GB
Cores  : 4 cores
Virtualization : yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine. Just run them on different ports and make sure you connect to the right one.